# Instagram oauth authorization too many requests from in app browser

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have sign in page with instagram authorization.
Authorization works fine with web browser and chrome.

Problem: Only in Instagram in app browser authorize link returns too many redirects error.
[screenshot][1]

Logs from server shows that it redirects to Instagram authorize link https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize

Does anyone faced these problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing exactly the same. We are trying to figure out a fix, but no way. In App Browser for Facebook App works good, it is only in app Instagram App. Looks like user in Instagram App is already logged in, but Instagram internally is not handling sessions properly. Looks an internal Instagram bug.

Comment: Cause Instagram doesnt accept support issues for old api, I have temporarily solved this problem by handling Instagram in app browser by user agent and displaying instruction to open page in native browser.